# Johnstone, Topos theory: families of arrows inducing the same sheaf condition

Tags: sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Johnstone, *Topos theory*, 0.3, page 13, asserts that, given a Grothendieck pretopology $P$, if the equalizer condition on a presheaf $F$ is satisfied for a family of arrows $R=\{U_i\to U\}$, then it is satisfied for every family $S=\{W_j\to U\}\supset R$.

By equalizer condition I mean that $$F(U)\to \prod_R F(U_i)\rightrightarrows \prod_{R\times R}F(U_i\times_U U_j),$$ with the natural restriction maps, is an equalizer.

I can't see why this is true. First of all, should I assume that $R$ is a covering in the given pretopology? Otherwise it would sound very strange to me. For example, take a discrete space of two points $X=\{p,q\}$, the pretopology being given by the topological coverings, and take $R=\{p\to X\}, S=\{p\to X,q\to X\}$; then the equalizer condition for $R$ means that every local section on $p$ comes from a global section on $X$. So take $F(p):=\{0\}, F(q)=\mathbb Z, F(\varnothing)=\{0\},F(X)=\{0\}$. This is a presheaf (with the natural maps, identity or zero) and satisfies the equalizer condition for $U=X$ and the family $R$ just defined: in
$$\{0\}\to \{0\} \rightrightarrows \{0\}$$ one can always take the global section $0$ on the left. However, the equalizer for $S$ is: $$\{0\}\to \{0\}\times \mathbb Z\rightrightarrows \{0\}\times \{0\}\times \{0\}\times \mathbb Z$$ where both arrows on the right are equal to $(0,1)\mapsto (0,0,0,1)$ (note that the "mixed" fiber products $p\times_X q$ and $q\times _X p$ are the empty set). So take $(0,1)\in \{0\}\times \mathbb Z$ in the central node of the last diagram. The maps on the right are the same, hence $F$ satisfies the equalizer condition for $S$ if and only if there exists $s\in F(X)=0$ s.t. $s|_{\{p\}}=0,s|_{\{q\}}=1$, but this is of course impossible.

Is my conterexample correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your $F$, what is the morphism $F(q)\to F(\varnothing)$?

Comment: The zero morphism. Is this a problem?

Comment: I think I'm just being confused by you notation. Writing $\{0\}$ as $0$, when $0$ is also common notation for an initial object, makes it look like you're trying to reason from an impossible presheaf. I think I see what you're doing now.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Fixed. $F$ should be a presheaf, isn't it?

Comment: Another possible counterexample in the first displayed answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856564/presheaves-over-a-discrete-space-are-necessarily-sheaves

Comment: Yes, that should be a presheaf. I'll have to think about this one; I've yet to be right when second guessing Johnstone, but his use of the word "clearly" may be overstating the case.

Comment: Your example is correct, but it seems to me that Johnstone's assertion is that contextually, only the case where $R,S$ are covering families is of interest, since the larger point is that the equalizer condition on certain 'saturated' covering families suffices, instead of a requirement on all covering families.